# Using subreport inside an SSRS table/tablix cell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

In my application I have a report with one subreport contained inside a table cell.  Within the SubreportProcessing event handler I supply a different set of data foreach instance of the subreport.  In VS 2008 this worked okay.  However, when I switched over to VS2010 and upgraded the report file format, the behavior changed.  All subreport instances in the master table now contain the data that I supplied for the first table row.  My code looks like this

```
void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    // _index is a global variable that is reset to zero in the DataBind procedure.
    Trip currentTrip = _trips[_index];

    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSourceName", currentTrip.Items));

    _index++;
}
```

Is this the intended behavior?  How can I now supply different datasets for multiple instances of the same subreport inside a table?

Thanks in advance.

Vladislav

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code where you attach to the SubreportProcessing event? Do you do that right after report creation, or at a later stage?

Comment: I do that manually inside the Form's constructor following the call to the InitializeComponent() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some poking around and tinkering with my code, I found a workaround. The solution is to create a dummy parameter in the subreport, which you then need to bind to a field in the tablix dataset.  Any field will do as long as both the subreport parameter and the tablix dataset field are type-compatible.  You don't have to do anything with the parameter in the subreport, but now SSRS displays multiple instances of the same subreport, a separate one for each row in the tablix.

Hope this will be helpful for someone else, too.

Vladislav